# How to generate summary report with nested collection using Java 8 streams?

Tags: java-8

I have a list of objects with class like this:

```
class TestResult{
  int userId;
  Set<String> subjects; 
  int score;
}
```

I want to produce a summary of score for each userId in each subject

```
Map<String,Map<Integer, Integer>>
```

The outer map has subject as key. The inner map has userId as key, sum of scores as the value.

Comment: Nice. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Added the class name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Please note: in the following, I refere to your (currently unnamed) class as `MixedScores`)

Let's a define a method `sumScores` which takes a `Collection<MixedScores>` and returns a `Map<String, Map<Integer, Integer>>` composed as you asked for.

You could use a local class `SingleScore` to help in splitting a single `MixedScores` instance in multiple instances, then group them by subject, by userId, and finally summing up all scores found.

In code:

```
Map<String, Map<Integer, Integer>> sumScores(Collection<MixedScores> scores) {
    class SingleScore {
        int userId;
        String subject;
        int score;

        SingleScore(MixedScores mixedScores, String subject) {
            this.userId = mixedScores.userId;
            this.subject = subject;
            this.score = mixedScores.score;
        }

        String getSubject() {
            return subject;
        }

        int getUserId() {
            return userId;
        }

        int getScore() {
            return score;
        }
    }

    return scores.stream()
            .flatMap(x -> x.subjects.stream().map(subject -> new SingleScore(x, subject)))
            .collect(groupingBy(SingleScore::getSubject,
                    groupingBy(SingleScore::getUserId, summingInt(SingleScore::getScore))));
}
```

Of course, there are some imports:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.summingInt;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: Why are you providing a full fledged solution without any effort from TO?

Comment: I see your point, @Flown; alas, I saw your comment to OP *after* answering question, which seemed straightforward to me, but admittedly showed little or no research effort, as you have noticed. Perhaps I should have looked at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users earlier. Sorry

Comment: Nice. But do we have to create a local class?

Comment: @JunruiTao Actually no but this is left as exercise. Hint: `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<K, V>`.

Comment: @Flown Nice, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another way without creating a new class, suggested by @Flown

```
                scores.stream()
                    .flatMap(x -> x.subjects.stream()
                            .map(subject -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Entry<Integer, Integer>>(subject,
                                    new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, Integer>(x.userId, x.score))))
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry<String, Entry<Integer, Integer>>::getKey,
                            Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getValue().getKey(),
                                    Collectors.summingInt((p -> p.getValue().getValue())))));
```